# Comic/tabletop RPG about mice with swords and shields going on adventures

Tags: story-identification, comics, rpg

I know I am not crazy, and it's within the last 5 years that I've seen the stories and the Tabletop RPG with the same characters. 
But for the life of me I cannot remember the Title.
What is worse; I can't find it at the book store in the normal section where it was placed, my comic store had it but is now also gone, and I can not find it on the internet.

Description:
It's about a group of (5-7), I think field mice, or at least small rodents.
They wore tunics, like that of link from zelda, and used swords and shields and went on adventures.
It's Fantasy based that came in a hard bound cover, with pictures of the critters and their adventures and enemies.
What is the name of this comic/story/ttRPG?

Comment: In addition, there are quite a few questions at the RPG SE site on mouse guard, and once you get enough rep you can chat/ask questions there as well. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=mouse+guard

Comment: This is a very different game, but I thought of it first from your description, so I considered it worth linking as a comment: http://www.plaidhatgames.com/games/mice-and-mystics

Comment: That is very interesting. Thank you, asfallows

Comment: If you want to read some books similar to this style, there is the **Redwall** series I believe it's called.  Not a game, but interesting books.  I read it when I was younger.  It was a good intro to fantasy.

Comment: Thank you, Dphil, for you suggestion. I will look into them.
It's been a long time since I've seen 'The Secret of Nimh'. But I have to give it credit for being the first animation to turn me on to small critters fighting evil.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Could be [Mouse Guard](http://www.mouseguard.net/books/role-playing-game/) - a comic by David Petersen, also an RPG.

Comment: Looks like Darth Satan got there a minute before me :-)

Comment: have a +1 to welcome you to the site anyway :)

Answer (score 21):

Mouse Guard

[image]

I'm not personally familiar with this canon, but I am aware of it.

Comment: @GeistvonPA If the answer helped, click the little checkbox icon to mark it as Accepted, and give a little rep to the answerer!

Comment: Sorry. still new at how to give rep-points and I never even realized that was a check, I thought it was a Down-Down-Arrow. Thank you Avner, for pointing that out.

Comment: @GeistvonPA - to be honest, I don't need the reputation. Feel free to give the accept to the other answer if you wish; I gave a picture but I at least think that the other has more useful info.

Answer (score 3):

Also please note that there is a non-related to Mouseguard board game about mice named ["Mice and Mystics"](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/games/mice-and-mystics) and a [recently successful finished kickstarter campaign for a Mouse Guard](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/burningwheel/mouse-guard-swords-and-strongholds) board game.

Comment: Yes, AsFallows, suggested "Mice and Mystics" as well. It seems like something my son and g/f would enjoy playing, since we are all D&D/GURP players as well.